# Spring Integration: create dynamic directories using ftp:outbound-adapter

Tags: spring-integration

We would like to be able to change the FTP directory on a channel, after the channel has been created. In our particular use case, the subdirectory for an FTP put is determined at runtime.for ex: we have daily reports uploaded by users.it should be store in ftp server in day wise folders. ex: `test/reports/27-11-2012/abc.pdf`, `test/reports/28-11-2012/abc.pdf` etc..

some what Like this

```
<int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter id="ftpOutbound" channel="ftpChannel" remote-directory="remoteDirectoryPath" 
   session-factory="ftpClientFactory" />
```

remoteDirectoryPath - it should append runtime

Please Anybody can give us solution?

Answer (score 1):

Use `remote-directory-expression`

@beanName.method() is currently not available in this expression; you will need to use SpEL for the directory generation...

```
"'test' + T(java.io.File).separator + new java.text.SimpleDateFormat('yyyyMMDD').format(new java.util.Date())"
```

Comment: Hi Gary,
Thanks for valuable comments.it helps me to dig into more on SpEL.I followed your comments and done the configration.but unfortunately i got bean resolver exception.

SpelEvaluationException: No bean resolver registered in the context to resolve access to bean

Can you help me where i done the mistake?

<context:component-scan base-package="com.integration"/>

<int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter id="ftpOutbound" channel="ftpChannel" remote-file-separator="/" 
  remote-directory-expression="@ftpBean.getDirectory()"
   session-factory="ftpClientFactory" auto-create-directory="true"  />

Comment: @Configuration(value="ftpBean")
public class FTPBean {
 
 private String directory;
 
 @Bean
 public FTPBean ftpBean(){
  return new FTPBean();
 }

 public String getDirectory(){
  return "test"+File.separator+new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMDD").format(new java.util.Date());
 }
 
 public void setDirectory(String directory) {
  this.directory = directory;
 }

 
}

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, @beanName syntax is not available for expressions in that context - I'll open up an improvement JIRA. In the meantime, you can create the string directly in the SpEL expression; I will modify my answer to show that.

Comment: Thanks Gary.some what i succeed getting remote directory from bean method using SpEL.but here my concern is how i need to concatenate static directories.
Ex: public String generate(){
         return "test"+File.separator+new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMDD").format(new java.util.Date());
}
suppose if i keep just return SimpleDateFormat then able create direcory in ftp server.but failed when i try to concatenate static directories prefix and postfix.

Comment: Here i just used  remote-directory-expression="#{@ftpBean.getDirectory()}" as seen in SpEL.

Comment: Here i just used  remote-directory-expression="#{@ftpBean.getDirectory()}" as seen in SpEL.
because why i am using through bean.method is there i should use username for folder name on every day uploading files. 
test/28-11-2012/username/filename.pdf

Comment: Using the #{} syntax will only be evaluated once, during context initialization - it won't change daily.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a directory/path at Runtime into ftp:outbound-channel-adapter.
I am coping the data over here. You can check this out.
This is working for me.

**xml side:**

```
<int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter id="ftpOutboundAdapter" session-factory="ftpSessionFactory"
    channel="sftpOutboundChannel"
    remote-directory-expression="@targetDir.get()"
    remote-filename-generator="fileNameGenerator"/>

<bean id="targetDir" class="java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference">
    <constructor-arg value="D:\PATH\"/>
</bean>
```

In this block...`remote-directory-expression="@targetDir.get()"`
is used for setting the directory/path at runtime.

**Java side:**

```
AtomicReference<String> targetDir = (AtomicReference<String>)appContext.getBean("targetDir", AtomicReference.class);
    targetDir.set("E:\PATH\");
```

By, this you can set your path.